# Can not parse JSON share document.\nRequest body:\n\nError:\nnull

Tags: python, json, linkedin-api

I am trying to send a request to Linkedin's rest share api. I have been receiving this error message:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Can not parse JSON share document.\nRequest body:\n\nError:\nnull",
  "requestId": "ETX9XFEI7N",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1437910620120
}
```

The request is send through the following python code:

```
import requests,json


auth_token = "some auth token"

url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token="+auth_token

headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','x-li-format':'json'}


data = {
              "comment":"Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
              "content":{
                        "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
                        "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
                        "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
                        "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
                        },
              "visibility":{
                        "code": "anyone"
                           }
        }



response = requests.post( url , json= data , headers=headers )


return HttpResponse( response )
```

I made sure that I followed all the instructions in their [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) and can't find the mistake I am making.

Note: i have tried json=data and data=data both are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `content-type` from the `headers` dictionary.

`requests` sets the correct Content-Type when using the `json` keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have three basic problems:

1. Please read the [documentation on oauth2](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2); because you are not passing in the token correctly.
2. The share URL [does not take a oauth2_token argument](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin).
3. You have the wrong content-type header.